# How I can create a file into a ServNet Environment?

Tags: java

I have a JavaWeb application on a Jelastic server, there I need to send an email with an attachment, at the time of development the behavior is correct and sends the file along with the message, but when executing it on the server the file I need to attach is not generated and I don't understand the reason.

I tried to create excel files, then I went to jasperreports to generate a pdf, however it is the same result ... the file is not generated. Of course obtain a nice error... somebody can help me?

My code to generate a file.

```
String relativeFilePath = rootFiles("REPOS") + propiedades.get("fileName") + ".jrxml";
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listData);
String jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(relativeFilePath);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap(), beanCollectionDataSource);
String relativeOutput = rootFiles("TEMP") + propiedades.get("fileName") + " " + properties.get("razonSocial") + ".pdf";
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, relativeOutput);
```

The error....

```
08-Aug-2019 22:07:51.778 SEVERE [http-nio-80-exec-2] net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJdtCompiler$1.findType Compilation error
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:298)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJdtCompiler$1.findType(JRJdtCompiler.java:255)....

08-Aug-2019 22:07:51.784 SEVERE [http-nio-80-exec-2] estaciones.controllers.MbResultadosRevision.enviarCorreo null
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
/*
^
1 errors

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:204)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:241)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:157)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:116)
```

Comment: What version of jasperreports library is used? rootFiles code is also required as well as relativeFilePath variable to make a decision on a solution.

Comment: I'm using Jasper 5.5.0.  In development ambient (in mi PC) it Works.